# Where do WP files go in AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS and not familiar at all. I have followed the steps on  http://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/07/wordpress-on-aws-beanstalk-rds/ and had no problems at all except for having no idea about the SSH to manage your files and DB part. My question is 1) is there another way to access files? 2) Where are the files uploaded? I am guessing S3, but have no idea.

Comment: what files are you referring to?

Comment: That tutorial you link to is wrong in many ways. You should never SSH into a beanstalk server and manually edit files, because AWS might add or delete servers automatically to your beanstalk environment based on load. I suggest finding a better tutorial, or finding a Wordpress hosting service that requires less technical knowledge than Elastic Beanstalk.